# Word correction program in java

Tags: java, javascript, python, words

I need to implement a program to handle a word correction / suggestion system.
 - if input is given as 'freind', it should suggest 'friend'.

For this I have a GUI containing a text area alone!

Suggest to me a way to accomplish this. If not in Java, you can also suggest me in Python, using javascript also because I can use those as well.

Thanx in advance. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are lots of opensource spell checker available

http://spellerpages.sourceforge.net/

http://jazzy.sourceforge.net/